# how can I give an array variable in maxima a value?

Tags: maxima

I've got

```
expand(product(1-p*a[i], i, 0, 1));
```

now I want to substitute a complex value for a[0] and a[1]:

```
subst(array_make([(-%i)-1,%i-1]), a, expand(product(1-p*a[i], i, 0, 1)));
```

help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maxima's handling of arrays is somewhat inconsistent. Here's a couple of ideas to get the result you want.

(I notice that your first input has `%1` instead of `%i`, I guess that's a typographic error.)

(1) Substitute a value for each subscripted variable.

```
myexpr: expand (product (1 - p*a[i], i, 0, 1));
subst ([a[0] = (-%i)-1, a[1] = %i - 1], myexpr);
```

(2) Substitute a value for the array. I'll use `ev` to do that because it appears that `subst` has a bug in it; I'll file a bug report about that.

Maxima doesn't have a built-in function to create an array with the contents of a list, so I'll define a helper function `array_from` for that.

```
myexpr: expand (product (1 - p*a[i], i, 0, 1));
array_from(l) := fillarray (make_array (any, length(l)), l);
ev(myexpr, a = array_from([(-%i)-1, %i - 1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
expand(subst(1.0*%i-1.0, a(1), subst(-1.0*%i-1.0, a(0), expand(product(1-s/a(i), i, 0, 1)))));
```